# How do finalizers work?

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to figure out how the GC/finalizers in c# work so I wrote the following program. But after the ReadKey the finalizer is called 36193 times. I thought it should be called just once when the program finishes and the AppDomain is unloading. What am I missing here, how does this work?

```
    private class GCAnalyzer
    {
        private static int count = 0;
        ~GCAnalyzer()
        {
            if (!AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload())
            {
                count++;
                GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);
                Console.WriteLine("GC " + count);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        new GCAnalyzer();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: have you read the msdn documentation?

Comment: it looks like you are wanting the garbage collector to recollect it.

Comment: Why do you `ReRegisterForFinalize` ?

Comment: I wonder why it stopped

Comment: @NSGaga probably the application terminated.

Comment: it stops much earlier for me.

Comment: not for me, it doesn't :)

Comment: Use `Environment.HasShutdownStarted` instead.

Comment: It is not clear to me why `Environment.HasShutdownStarted` is true but `IsFinalizingForUnload` is false; I've sent email to the documentation manager asking for this to be investigated.

Answer (score 2):

If I read this right then you are calling ~GCAnalyzer() when the object is "unlinked", and during that code, you say it is not ready to be "unlinked" via GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this), meaning at next check it still not used, and its end code is run ... reregistering itself ... and so forth.

Comment: I was thinking that the finalizer would get called when GC collection is taking place, after that the AppDomain would be unloaded so the object wont reregister itself again. So what happens then? The finalizer thread keeps calling this finalizer before the AppDomain gets unloaded??

Answer (score 0):

The key was to add the !Environment.HasShutdownStarted check. Then on every collection the finalizer is called and put back in the finalization list. So in this program the finalizer is called 3 times. Twice for every GC.Collect and then its registered back in the finalization list, the third time when the app shuts down and then its not reregistered so it can shut dowb gracefully.

```
    private class GCAnalyzer
    {
        private static int count = 0;
        ~GCAnalyzer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GC " + count);
            if (!AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload() &&!Environment.HasShutdownStarted)
            {
                count++;
                GC.ReRegisterForFinalize(this);                    
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        new GCAnalyzer();

        Console.ReadKey();

        GC.Collect();

        Console.ReadKey();

        GC.Collect();
    }
```